# Sorting a column in pandas dataframe using two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

```
   P_id Sim no_of_occurance
0   1   0.00    4
1   2   0.25    3
2   3   0.25    5
3   4   0.25    5
4   5   0.25    6
5   6   0.25    4
6   7   0.50    6
7   8   0.50    2
8   9   0.50    5
9   10  0.25    4
10  11  0.25    6
11  12  0.50    4
12  13  0.50    4
13  14  0.25    4
```

I want to sort `P_id`  based on the corresponding descending values in `Sim'` column for each row and for rows where `Sim` values are same, I want that `P_id` to come first whose `no_of_occurance` is higher.

Desired output-

```
P_id  Sim    no_occurance
 7    0.50    6
 9    0.50    5
 12   0.50    4
 13   0.50    4
 8    0.50    2
 5    0.25    6
 11   0.25    6
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: You are looking for `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`. Here is a [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["Sim", "no_of_occurance"], ascending=[False, False])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    P_id   Sim  no_of_occurance
6      7  0.50                6
8      9  0.50                5
11    12  0.50                4
12    13  0.50                4
7      8  0.50                2
4      5  0.25                6
10    11  0.25                6
2      3  0.25                5
3      4  0.25                5
5      6  0.25                4
9     10  0.25                4
13    14  0.25                4
1      2  0.25                3
0      1  0.00                4
```

Comment: i think `df.sort_values(by =["Sim", "no_of_occurance"],ascending=False )`  , do we need `False` two times?

Comment: @KarnKumar Yes, one `False` is enought. I wanted to be just explicit.